# Java - calculating the sum of a series of numbers

Tags: java

i am trying to calculate the sum of the first 16 elements of the series 1, 3, 9, 27, 81.... The code does so by first CREATING a suitable instance of Geometric that will be of TYPE Seq.

```
public class Geometric implements Seq {

private double b;
public Seq s;
public double sum;

public Geometric(double a) {

    this.b = a;
}


public double valAtIndex(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Math.pow(b, i);
}

public double total() {

    s = new Geometric(3.0);
    for (int a = 0; a < 16; a++) {

        int c = -1;
        sum = sum + s.valAtIndex(c = c + 1);
        c++;

    }
    return sum;
}

public double getSum() {

    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

Not sure if i am doing this the long way round? It isnt working yet, eclipse is saying i need to change the modifier of sum to static?

Comment: There is a closed form for the sum of a geometric series.  See the wikipedia article on[Geometric Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it wants `sum` to be static because you are trying to reach sum inside a static method, `main`. You can't reach non-static fields inside static methods. You should create an instance of `Geometric` inside `main`, then you should call the variable `sum`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Geometric geo = new Geometric(some_number);
    System.out.println(geo.sum);
}
```

Also, your way of doing things is not a good way of object-oriented programming concept.

You are returning the total of the series from a method, but you are also storing it in a field called `sum`, and you are wanting `sum` before calculating it. Instead, you should get total from the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Geometric geo = new Geometric(3.0);
    System.out.println(geo.total());
}
```

Since the method `total` is specified for instances of this class, it shouldn't create a new instance to calculate the total, it should calculate the current instance's total.

```
public double total() {
    double temp = 1;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
        sum += temp;
        temp *= this.b;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you made this a bit more complicated then it needs to be.  Here's how I'd do it without using another class (the code can go in any class where you need to compute the sum):

```
int currentNumber = 1;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    sum += currentNumber;
    currentNumber *= 3;
}
```

The value of the sum of the terms in the geometric sequence will be stored in the variable `sum`.  Alternatively use the [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) for the sum of the terms in a geometric sequence:

```
int firstNumber = 1;
int multFactor = 3;
int numTerms = 16;
int sum = firstNumber * ((1 - multFactor ^ numTerms) / (1 - multFactor));
```

or in your case:

```
int sum = 1 * ((1 - 3^16) / (1 - 3));  // returns 21523360, the number you were trying to calculate
```

Comment: yeah that is a lot simpler, when i try to create an instance of seq e.g. `Seq s = new Geometric(3.0);
  System.out.println(s.total());`   as i have to create an instance of geometric of type Seq

Comment: but `Geometric s = new Geometric(3.0);
  System.out.println(s.total());` does work. Not sure if i have misunderstood the mock question, or if this is ok?

Comment: @nsc010 look at my post after the edit: I think the easiest way for you to do this would just be to use the closed form for the geometric series).

Answer (score 0):

> eclipse is saying i need to change the modifier of sum to static?

Because you are printing out `sum` in a static method `main(String[])`. You can't access an instance field from a static method. You need to create an instance of Geometric and get the `sum` from that instance.

Answer (score 0):

total and sum look like they're supposed to be static. I have no idea what getSum is for. But the real question is, why aren't you just adding up the numbers directly? You don't need a class for everything.